# Static variable is not initialized immediately

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public class variables {
    public static int edit{ get;set; }
}
```

And also tried:

```
public static int edit = 0;

public static int edit { get; set; } 

public static int edits { get { return edit; } }
```

Using the form

```
form:form1 {

    // Changing the value of variable to 1
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        variables.edit=1;
    }

    // Calling the new form where I'll use its value
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        form2 A=new form2();
        A.Show();
    }
}    

form:form2{

    // Showing the value of the variable in a message box
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
         MessageBox.show(variables.edit.ToSting());
    } 
}
```

The *Message* in all cases returned `0` least that call again. I need to know how to make the values initialize step as the first. I have to tab Use the many variable that keep data from one form to another and use in the load.

Comment: Thanks for let me know that here is only at English!!
I really need help
i didnt know why when i initialize the variable alfter the load it works but i need at load!

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're asking, but I will reopen the question in case others understand it better than I do. I'm the future, you may want to ask for help from a native English speaker or ask your questions at [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: sorry to say but really can't understand where your problem and what your question is

Comment: i change the value of the static variable at the last form but when i call it a the load of the another form it return without value.
if i close and open the form again it works! but i need it a the first

Comment: what about that : `static class Variables { public static int edits; }`  ?

Comment: Every thing its ok. the proble is that i have to call the form two time for the message show the value that i give it but it do just at load if i call it by a button it works a the first!

Comment: It was one of the pruve that i had done, using two variable try to see what was happing but it is not a the code i just say i try this one. static class Variables { public static int edits {get{return edit}}}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your class `variables` is static, not only the fields/properties:

```
public static class variables {
    public static int edit = 0;
}
```

Another source of problem with static classes is when you use one field/property when setting another:

```
public static class variables {
    public static int someValue = 2;
    public static int other = someValue + 3;
}
```

AFAIK, you can't be sure of what field/property will be set first by the static constructor at runtime, unless you set the values in the static constructor, like this:

```
public static class variables {
    static variables() {
        someValue = 0;
        other = someValue + 3;
    }

    public static int someValue;
    public static int other;
}
```

If you are declaring static fields/properties in a really non-static class, check for the problem above, and if nothing else is changing the static field/property in another place, even inside the non-static class.